# Search MacOS for a specific filename and send email if it exists

Tags: bash, macos, email

I'm really new with Mac and Linux in general but I'm trying to search for a specific license file and if it exists, send an email to report back.

So far I have this

```
 #!/bin/sh

FILE=/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/ExtensionPacks/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack/ExtPack-license.htm
CNAME = defaults read /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.smb.server NetBIOSName

if [ -f "$FILE"]; then

        echo "$FILE exists."
        echo "Found Addon on $CNAME" | cat $FILE | mail -s "$(echo -e $BODY.\nFrom: NoReply <noreply@domain.com>\n @domain.com\nContent-Type: text/html\n")" 'email@domain.com'

    else
        echo "$FILE does not exist"
    fi
```

I assume I'm missing something very easy/obvious, but I haven't found an answer that makes sense to me after a few searches.  Appreciate your time and any input.

Comment: Where do you set `BODY`?

Comment: Why are you putting all the headers in the `-s` option? That should just contain the subject.

Comment: You have an unmatched `"` at the end of the headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to use `$(...)` to assign the result of the `defaults read` command to a variable.
2. You can't pipe input to `cat` and also have `cat` read from a file. I suspect you want `Found Addon on $CNAME` to be the mail subject, so that should be in the `-s` option, not piped in. You can use input redirection to read the message text from the file.
3. The `-s` option is just for setting the subject, you can't add other headers that way. The `mail` command doesn't have options to set other headers.

```
#!/bin/sh

FILE=/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/ExtensionPacks/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack/ExtPack-license.htm
CNAME=$(defaults read /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.smb.server NetBIOSName)

if [ -f "$FILE"]; then
    echo "$FILE exists."
    mail -s "Found Addon on $CNAME" 'email@domain.com' < "$FILE"
else
    echo "$FILE does not exist"
fi
```